# Android Studio- Web View not connecting to local server

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview, emulation

I have Android Studio and I have used all kind of address to connect to local development server to open an html file from my browser of Emulator.

I tried below address

```
1. 10.0.2.2
2. 10.0.2.2:portnumber
3. mylocalip:port and only mylocalip/filename
4. 127.0.0.1 with and without port  
5. 192.168.0.1
```

Did I need some other settings which I am forgetting ?

Comment: Can you open your local html on other PCs in your LAN? Maybe your local server is not configured to expose it's contents to other devices but itself?

Comment: More code please and post logcat or the displayed message in the webView if available. Moreover, try access your server from the web browser of the phone/emulator to check if it works

Comment: @BNK.. I tried to open the html on webbrowser and it shows "WEB Page not available "..

Comment: @azurh.. The only message that I ddi not understand is coming in log cat is "24619-24619/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"

Comment: @azurh: don't worry about that message. From the webbrowser, means that your phone/emulator cannot access the developement server, you need to check if between them has firewall or other network policy set to prevent access? Moreover, try build a development on your local PC then test access

Comment: Basically I have created it on my local machine itself and trying to open the HTML on same machine. I am not sure about the all or other network policy , where it has been setup or not. Let me try to find it.

Comment: I tried all option and find neither internet is working in my emulator. I did not find the option to configure emulator in Android Studio.